# ASP.NET.VB Answer to change a GridView cell value from an value of [1] to a value of [High]

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a very simple question that, when looking for the answer, I can find everything I need as long as it is C#. VB, on the other hand seems to be seriously lacking. I have a gridview named GridViewCL. Its data source is SqlDataSource4, which calls for all call log records from the SQL table FS_CALL_LOG where a Column called CLMARKER equals an [R]. A standard and very basic Select Statement that works like a charm after a button click. When the grid binds and appears. Column (6) of the grid shows data from the database Column called CLPRIORITY, which will either be a number 1, 2 or 3. Nothing complicated. I even turned the column into a template so I can do some stuff with it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRIORITY">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
 Text='<%# Eval("CLPRIORITY") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

All I want to do is to simply display in the grid a Value of [High] if the value from the database is a [1], [Medium] if it is a [2] and [Low] if it is a [3]. Nothing fancy. Months of learning C# do not help if company owners want to use VB.

You would think a VB answer would take one or two attempts to find results for an answer on the web but, alas, the World seems to favor the C-Sharpers out there. Either that or I'm asking the wrong question, which could also be my problem. Anybody out there who would like to answer this very basic problem? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Is this GridView bound to DataTable?

Comment: as a side note, you should tag this question asp.net, and webforms. But do see the answer I have below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all is fine.

So, you are filling this from a database.

So for things like:
Set set the color of a grid cell to "red" for a given city, or doing formatting on the fly?

And you markup looks quite fine.

The cool event that lets you say change color of a control, or do whatever?

It is the row datbound event.

So, click on the grid in the designer, show the properties sheet, and select this event:

[image]

Ok, so now in your code stub, try this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    Dim GRow As GridViewRow = e.Row

    If GRow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        '
        Dim Mylable As Label = GRow.FindControl("Label1")

        Select Case Mylable.Text
            Case 1
                Mylable.Text = "High"
                ' bonus if 1 lets make the background red
                Mylable.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Case 2
                Mylable.Text = "Medium"
            Case 3
                Mylable.Text = "Low"
        End Select

    End If
```